# On convergence of derangement sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits, limits-without-lhopital, derangements

> The portion of permutations that do not leave any number in its place is $\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\cdots+(-1)^n\left(\frac1{n!}\right)$. As $n$ grows, this sum gets closer to a certain number, which is approximately $0.367879$. That is, in general more than one third of the permutations leave no number in its place.
>
> The exact value of this number is $\frac1e$, where $e$ is the famous **Euler constant**.

This is an extract from a book I've been reading, and it says the sequence converges to the reciprocal of Euler's number as n tends to *large values*.

1. What do they mean by convergence of a discrete, not continuous, sequence?
2. Could someone please show *how* and *why* the derangement sequences converges to $\frac1e$? (Treating the expression mathematically, using theorems of limits etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: $$e^x=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^k}{k!}}$$
$$e^{-1}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }(-1)^{k}{\frac {1}{k!}}$$

Comment: It has been suggested that most people would expect that if you took two shuffled standard decks of 52 playing cards, the chance that there is at least one $n$ such that the $n$th card in one deck exactly matches the $n$th card in the other, is less than $1/2$, when in fact the chance differs from $1-1/e$ by less than $1/(53!)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) All sequences are discrete- the elements are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, if you prefer). An infinite series is the limit of a sequence of finite sums.

2) Recall that the Taylor expansion of $e^{x}$ is:
$$e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$

Now $1/e = e^{-1}$. So:

$$e^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}$$

**Edit:** The derangement number:
$$D_{n} = n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{i}}{i!}$$

This number has combinatorial interpretation via the principle of inclusion-exclusion. We count the number of permutations which fix no points. For each $i \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, we count the number of permutations which fix at least $i$ points. We select the $i$ targeted fixed points in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways. The remaining $n-i$ elements can be freely varied in $(n-i)!$ ways. By rule of product, this yields $\binom{n}{i}(n-i)! = \frac{n!}{i!}$. So by the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, we have that:

$$D_{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i} \binom{n}{i} (n-i)! = n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{i}}{i!}$$

As desired.

Comment: Is there any way of interpreting it combinatorially?

Comment: @user28968 See my edit.